# What happens if I pick up an upgrade for a fully upgraded item?

Tags: vampire-survivors

Let's say I play on a stage that starts with passive items on the map (Clover, Spinach, etc). Typically if you already have an item, finding the same item on the map will upgrade it to the next level.

What happens if I pick up an item upgrade after I've already upgraded the item to max level? Does the item upgrade beyond max level?

Answer (score 0):

It "upgrades" the item, but it doesn't gain any more stats.